# Enthought PyLab/Canopy in Windows 8 - (Academic) missing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, enthought, canopy

I installed the academic version of Canopy and got PyLab, Canopy shortcuts on my desktop.
When I try running PyLab from the shortcut on my desktop, I get a command window that opens with this:

```
UserWarning: The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. All its subpackages have been moved to the top `IPython` level.
  warn("The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. "
Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Aug  8 2013, 05:30:12) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Eventloop or matplotlib integration failed. Is matplotlib installed?
```

Strangely, when I run python2.7 from the command line, it lists matplotlib as installed.  When I run the Canopy package manager, it says that matplotlib 1.3.0 is installed.

What is wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple version of python installed?  Looks like your paths are fouled up.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the Pylab shortcut is broken through Canopy 1.1.1. You can edit it manually (replace "System" with "User" in the Target path), or open the "Canopy Command Prompt" from the Start Menu, then type `ipython --pylab=qt`

Also note that the Python shell panel, in the Canopy GUI application itself, runs Ipython QtConsole in Pylab mode by default, probably the easiest way to run Pylab, alongside an editor that is linked to that Pylab session.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which version is 'this release' so this answer is still clear in a few years?

Comment: Added "through Canopy 1.1.1"

Comment: Thank you.  Editing the shortcut seems to have fixed the problem.